# Почему я не могу изменить объект, полученный через метод?

Tags: javascript

Учу после джавы джаваскрипт и не могу понять, почему я не могу изменить арей, который получил через гет метод?

```js
class Car {
  movements = [124, 32, 123, 50, 12];

  getMovements() {
    return this.movements;
  }
}
const ferrari = new Car();

ferrari.movements = [1]; // Ничего не меняется
console.log(ferrari.movements);
```

Если я явно укажу, что это геттер, то могу изменить уже объект.

```
   get getMovements() {
        return this.movements;
      }
```

Почему это не работает с обычным методом?

Comment: В приведённом вами коде всё меняется.

Comment: у вас тег javascript, а вопрос по java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы, вероятно, хотели спросить вот про это:

```js
class Car {
  _movements = [124, 32, 123, 50, 12];

  get movements() {
    return this._movements;
  }
}
const ferrari = new Car();

console.log(ferrari.movements);
ferrari.movements = [1]; // Ничего не меняется
console.log(ferrari.movements);
```

Надо так:

```js
class Car {
  _movements = [124, 32, 123, 50, 12];

  get movements() {
    return this._movements;
  }
  
  set movements(value) {
    this._movements = value;
  }
}
const ferrari = new Car();

console.log(ferrari.movements);
ferrari.movements = [1]; // меняется
console.log(ferrari.movements);
```