# Почему Time Complexity для add() в sorted LinkedList - O(n)?

Tags: java, time-complexity

Столкнулся с сайтом вопрос-ответ. Нашел вот такую цитату:

> Какое худшее время работы метода add() для LinkedList?

Ответ

> O(N) - будет при добавление элемента в отсортированный список, а также
> при добавлении  элемента с помощью метода add(index, value).

Абсолютно не понял, какой отсортированный список может быть в LinkedList? Только если мы сами его будем сортировать, но как наша сортировка тогда вливает на метод add()? Выходит, добавление элементов в LinkedList ( кроме add(index, value ) будет всегда O(1).

Буду очень рад, если вы меня поправите.

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1339156/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для добавления нового элемента в сортированный связанный список нужно найти место куда его добавлять, то есть в худшем случае - пройти по всему списку.

Comment: Благодарю, я понимаю, как это звучит на словах, но не могу понять на практике.

LinkedList имеет какую-то реализацию, которая автоматически сортирует элементы? Я думал, методу add() все равно, он кидает элемент в начало, а потом мы уже можем отсортировать отдельным методом.

Comment: @Mark_Daniels `LinkedList` *может* иметь такую реализацию. Речь идет о гипотетически сортированном списке.